# When the program is running: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ; What should I do?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I use selenium to simulate a login, enter the site and open the hover list in the sidebar, after clicking on an option, a new page is opened normally, but the program runs with an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/chromedriver')

o_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.get('********')

print(o_handle)

username_input = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
password_input = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/input')

username_input.send_keys('h****o')

password_input.send_keys('*****')

login_button = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/button')

login_button.click()

time.sleep(1)

liangshoufenxi = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="sidebar__wrap"]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[13]/div/span')
liangshoufenxi.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sidebar__wrap"]/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span')))

ribao = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="sidebar__wrap"]/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span')

ribao.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 130)

new_window_handle = wait.until(EC.new_window_is_opened(o_handle))
```

Helpful hints to solve this, thanks!

I've tried to get a new window handle and increase the wait time, but both report the same error; I'd like to know how to troubleshoot this, or can I see why I'm not getting a new window?

Comment: I would check EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2) instead.  Try/catch, if timeout reached, check size of returned driver.current_window_handles handle array.  (A new window may not have been launched... )